# Designing an Oracle APEX DB for an Application - Mental Road Block

Tags: oracle-apex, master-detail

I need some help getting past a road block I've come across in creating my application in APEX.

This application will be to track financial disbursements from a company. It will utilize a one to many relationship. One associate to many different transaction details.

Using Quick SQL in APEX 19.2 I have created a couple tables. DISB and DISB_DTLS

```
DISB
  Assignor vc
  Processor vc
  RCVD_DA date
  PROC_DA date
  ACT_NO number
  APPROVER vc
  STATUS vc
  NOTES vc

DISB_DTLS
  AMT number
  etc
  etc...
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to have the primary table DISB be for the associate. Hence "One Associate to Many Disbursements. However, we have so many details that it would make the interactive grid APEX uses way to big and squished when doing a Master Detail form. Yet the only way to modify two tables or a view would be a master detail form. That's why I put some disbursement info in the primary table DISB and not the DTLS table.

I know there are some creative applications out there, and need some help discovering what I can do in regards to updating multiple tables from one form, if possible. Or alternatives. I want to make this process easy for the associates. This was all in one spreadsheet at one point.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't compromise Database design over the UI.
What you can do in this case is filter segmentation.

Complete your Master-Detail as initially thought.
Some detail columns can be logically grouped so I would put some filters somewhere on the page which the users selects a Logical group of columns to be displayed. That way you hide/show the columns to ensure they fit on the screen. Think of Filters as radio buttons or even checkboxes, let the user choose what shows on the screen.